# VBA - Copying Some rows (of one column) from a 2-D array to a particular column of another array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array, slice

I am stuck. I am trying to copy some selected rows from one column of a 2-D array to a particular column of another 2-D Array. I have tried all my knowledge, but to no avail.

```
Sub TestIndxPst()
    Dim varArray As Variant
    
    ReDim varArray(1 To 4, 1 To 3)
    Dim vaOut As Variant
    ReDim vaOut(1 To 4, 1 To 3)
    RowNumArray = Evaluate("transpose(Row(1" & ":" & 5 & "))")
    varArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:I7")
    Application.Index([G9:I12], , 2) = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(varArray, Array(2, 3, 5, 6), 2))
    vaOut = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(varArray, Array(2, 3, 5, 6), 2))
    Application.Index(vaOut, , 2) = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(varArray, Array(2, 3, 5, 6), 2))
    For i = LBound(vaOut) To UBound(vaOut)
        Debug.Print vaOut(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can see that I can do this while writing to an excel range using `Application.Index([G9:I12], , 2) = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(varArray, Array(2, 3, 5, 6), 2))`

I can also do that when I output it to the first column using `vaOut = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(varArray, Array(2, 3, 5, 6), 2))`

But as soon as I am trying to put the result in column 2 of out array here,  `Application.Index(vaOut, , 2) = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(varArray, Array(2, 3, 5, 6), 2))`. I get **application-defined or object defined error**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Best way to approach this would be to use loops to perform the transfer, instead of Index/Transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Application.Index(vaOut, , 2) = ..` - *Any help is highly appreciated*

- 1. `ReDim varOut` & `ReDim vaOut` get overruled by any eventual datafield assignment.
- 2. If you want to stick to the `Index` function by all means writing the rearranged values to a target range, I'd prefer an intermediate assignment
     something like

```
    Dim newArr
    newArr =  Application.Transpose(Application.Index(varArray, Array(2, 3, 5, 6), 2))
```

followed by

```
    Sheet1.Range("H9").Resize(Ubound(newArr),ubound(newArr,2)) = newArr
```

- 3. `Application.Index([G9:I12], , 2) = ..` builds no virtual array,
     it describes just the receiving *target range* which simply is H9:H12 then.

**Main issue**

If, however you want to enter the newArr values to the same or another array column,
this is simply not possible in one go by a
construction like
`Application.Index(vaOut, , 2) = ..` *(though ressembling to your previous target range code)* - you'll have to loop (e.g. through newArr and enter values to another predefined array) as @TimWilliams suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for for the explanation. I also suspected that slicing the array and using that to populate columns of another array is not possible, though I was not sure why. My issue is, the array will have 100-200K records and 20-40 columns. I am guessing, looping through the array will cause performance issue; am I wrong in my assumptions.

Comment: @Saugata a) Using VBA your solutions will be more time consuming with too complicated Index rearrangements for great data sets; note furthermore that `Application.Transpose` is limited in size ( ~65k or 2^16-1), seems to be partially solved for Office 64 and `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`.  b) Oldie but goodie: [Arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/SortingArrays.aspx).